# How to solve: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' for mono-project?

Tags: apt, mono

whenever i try to run sudo apt update, i get this error:
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

However if i try to change to files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d to include: deb[arch=64] https://blablabla, I get another error saying that it doesn't support architecture 64. I also tried to include [arch=64] while trying to import the repo, but it didn't work.

Comment: There's no architecture "64", what you want is "amd64".